# Migrating to room, app crashes on startup with exception

Tags: android, android-room

Here's the code for the app:
https://github.com/sandy-8925/Checklist/tree/room_db

When I build this and start it up, app always crashes with the following exception. Note that I already had a previous version of this app with the plain Sqlite DB

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly
>   handle items(org.sanpra.checklist.activity.ChecklistItem).
>                                                                          Expected:
>                                                                         TableInfo{name='items', columns={checked=Column{name='checked',
>   type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   _id=Column{name='_id', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, desc=Column{name='desc', type='TEXT',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
>                                                                          Found:
>                                                                         TableInfo{name='items', columns={checked=Column{name='checked',
>   type='integer', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   _id=Column{name='_id', type='integer', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1}, desc=Column{name='desc', type='text',
>   notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
>
> at
>   org.sanpra.checklist.dbhelper.ItemsDatabase_Impl$1.validateMigration(ItemsDatabase_Impl.java:66)
>                                                                             at
>   android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:75)
>                                                                             at
>   android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
>                                                                             at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:299)
>                                                                             at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:194)
>                                                                             at
>   android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:93)
>                                                                             at
>   android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)
>                                                                             at
>   android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:193)
>                                                                             at
>   org.sanpra.checklist.activity.ItemsDao_Impl.fetchAllItems(ItemsDao_Impl.java:229)
>                                                                             at
>   org.sanpra.checklist.activity.ChecklistItemsCursorLoader.loadInBackground(ChecklistItemsCursorLoader.java:46)
>                                                                             at
>   org.sanpra.checklist.activity.ChecklistItemsCursorLoader.loadInBackground(ChecklistItemsCursorLoader.java:32)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:306)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:59)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:47)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:138)
>                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expected

> TableInfo{name='items', columns={checked=Column{name='checked',
>   type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   _id=Column{name='_id', type='INTEGER', **notNull=true**, primaryKeyPosition=1}, desc=Column{name='desc', type='TEXT',
>   **notNull=false**, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

Found

> TableInfo{name='items', columns={checked=Column{name='checked',
>   type='integer', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   _id=Column{name='_id', type='integer', **notNull=false**, primaryKeyPosition=1}, desc=Column{name='desc', type='text',
>   **notNull=true**, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

_id is nullable but Room expected it to be not null.

desc is not null but Room expected it is null

Comment: Thank you, I noticed that myself. I fixed it by adding a migration where I recreated the table with the schema that Room expected (using intermediate temporary table to hold the data meanwhile).  Unfortunately, Room doesn't allow us to manually specify "not null" status for Entity fields, and automatically expects primary key to be declared as not null, even though we'd have to specify that manually if we were using usual Android Sqlite code.

Comment: Probably too late now but Room should let you specify nullability. You might be able to use the NotNull or Nullable annotation on Java. But I know that using kotlin I can set the ? on the variable to make it nullable and Room respects that